# How does android handle GUI events?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I’m trying to understand what happens when a button is clicked in android. So I set up a couple of break points for a simple button click. The picture shows what happens when a button is clicked my questions are: (GUI generated events are events that are generated as a result of interaction with the gui for example Button Clicks, editing text etc…)

1-  Is Looper.loop() the main loop for the application or the OS looper ?

2-  Where does ViewRootImpl(handler).dispatchMessage(Message) reside? Application or OS?

3-  Can I intercept GUI generated events in the main looper ? if yes then how?

4-  Can we safely assume that all GUI generated events are handled in ViewRootImpl(handler).handleCallback(Message)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Looper.loop() the main loop for the application or the OS looper ?

I don't know what you think the "OS looper" is. The `Looper` runs in your process, if that's what you mean.

> Where does ViewRootImpl(handler).dispatchMessage(Message) reside? Application or OS?

I don't know what you think the "OS" is in this context. `ViewRootImpl` is a Dalvik-compiled class that is loaded into your Dalvik VM and its code executes within your process. Otherwise, you would not be able to see it in your stack trace.

> Can I intercept GUI generated events in the main looper ?

Only by modifying the firmware to replace various classes like `ViewRootImpl` with your own code.

> Can we safely assume that all GUI generated events are handled in ViewRootImpl(handler).handleCallback(Message)?

I certainly would not make that assumption. For example, not all applications use the widget framework (e.g., games).